# Display Advanced Custom Fields through a functions in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to add an array of Advanced Custom Fields values to the single product page in a WooCommerce website.

This fields are checkboxes the website admin will check and I want the values to show in the single product page.

I've already found how to show the values using this code on my child theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'deco_display_acf_field_under_images', 30 );
    function deco_display_acf_field_under_images() {
       echo the_field('cuidados');
    }
```

Where “cuidados” is the name of the field.

It works, but this only displays the values separated by commas.

Now I want to use a more advanced way of displaying the values like this example I've found on the ACF documentation for displaying checkboxes values:

```
<?php

// vars 
$colors = get_field('colors');


// check
if( $colors ): ?>
    <ul>
    <?php foreach( $colors as $color ): ?>
        <li><?php echo $color; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I don't know PHP but I know this won't work on my functions.php file because of the syntax.

Can you help me figure out how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it can be hard to learn a programming language at first, but it's very hard to help you without doing all the work for you when you are still not far enough into learning PHP to convert basic syntax. Additionally, I personally don't see a reason why the syntax in the example would not work if adapted sufficiently to your own data structure and variables.

Answer (score 1):

As the value of `get_field('cuidados')` is a string made of coma separated values, you could try the following:

```
$colors_str = get_field('colors');

if( ! empty($colors_str) ) {

    // Removing the space after the coma (if there is any)
    $colors_str = str_replace(', ', ',', $colors_str);

    // Convert the string as an array
    $colors = explode(',', $colors_str);

    // Html output
    echo '<ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $colors ) . '</li></ul>';
}
```

It should work… So in your hooked function:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'deco_display_acf_field_under_images', 30 );
function deco_display_acf_field_under_images() {
    global $product;

    $colors_str = get_field('colors', $product->get_id());

    if( ! empty($colors_str) ) {

        // Removing the space after the coma (if there is any
        $colors_str = str_replace(', ', ',', $colors_str);

        // Convert the string as an array
        $colors = explode(',', $colors_str);

        // Html output
        echo '<ul><li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $colors ) . '</li></ul>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Comment: Hi, @loictheaztec thanks for your help, I added the code to my functions.php (just changing the field name from the example to the actual field name): [link] (https://snag.gy/eE7OFb.jpg) but in the front end I just get an empty list tag: [link] (https://snag.gy/f3Xic4.jpg) Any ideas?

Comment: @CarlosRodríguez what is the output for `get_field('colors');`, I mean what do you get exactly please? … Nobody can realy answer your question as you should give an example of the output that you get for  `get_field('colors');`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
add_action('woocommerce_product_tabs', 'deco_display_acf_field_under_images', 30);

function deco_display_acf_field_under_images() {
// fields MUST be an array in the format array(a,b,c) (or [a,b,c])
$fields = the_field('cuidados');
if (is_string($fields)) $fields = explode(",", $fields);

// check
if ($fields): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach ($fields as $field): ?>
            <li><?php echo $field; ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; 
}
```

Comment: Hi @chatnoir, thanks for your help. That didn't work and I think it is because of the syntax as I mentioned in the question. I think I can't use the `<?php` tags in the functions.php so I need to figure out how to add this function with the proper format as the first code I presented and that it's already working. Any ideas?